# Please find the range of $V$ when $V = \frac {1} {X}$ & $0 <x<1 $

Tags: limits

if $0 <x<1 $ then what is the range of $V$ when

$V = \frac {1} {X}$

i tried to compute it by :

when $x=0$ then $V = \frac {1} {X}= \frac {1} {0} =undefined$

when $x=1$ then $V = \frac {1} {X}= \frac {1} {1} =1$

so it comes    $\quad undefined <v<1 $

but the book, which i am reading , is showing the range $\quad v>1$

Comment: "undefined" is not a number! Are there numbers other than integers?

Comment: @TCL no there is no more numbers other than integers.if i remove the undefined then it comes the range $v<1$. but still it doesn't match with the range $v>1$ written on the book.

Comment: @TCL the problem of range occurs from here "if $X\sim beta(p,q)$ find the distribution of $V=\frac{1}{X}$"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you mean "limit", I think you mean "range".

When $x$ decreases from just below one, $1/x$ increases from just above one. E.g. work out $1/0.999$ on a calculator, and understand why it's like that.

As $x$ gets very close to zero, $1/x$ gets bigger and bigger, tending to $+\infty$. Therefore, $v$ takes on everything bigger than 1.

Comment: thank you very much. Now it is quite clear to me. and you are right. it should be "range" not "limit".

Answer (score 0):

Consider $x > 0$. It immediately follows that $V > 0$.

Consider $x < 1$ and substitute $x = 1/V$ in that inequality.

So, we get:

$$\frac{1}{V} < 1$$

Multiplying both sides by $V$, we get:

$$1 < V$$

Note that the inequality sign does not flip because $V > 0$. Or in other words:

$$V > 1$$

Comment: this is also very nice explanation. Thank you too.